# Check if a fetched user exists in database. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to check a fetched user exists in DB. Suppose I assigned the authenticated user to a variable and the same user is deleted with another variable. But the first variable holds the value of the deleted user. So I want to check whether user data exists in the DB. Something like this.

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user1 = Auth::user();
$user1->delete();
if($user->existsInDB()){
     //
}
```

Comment: What do you get with `if($user->existsInDB()){`? Also, if you have deleted it manually, why would check if it exists in DB again?

Comment: I am deleting users category wise. Some users have more than one category.

Comment: Ok, then you delete the relation between that category and that user and not the user directly. Like, if you wanted  to delete users who have category `['abc','xyz']`, but the user actually was related to `['abc','xyz','def']`, so you lose the relation of that user with `def` if you delete the user directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#retrieving-models) you will see that there's a `fresh` method:

> The fresh method will re-retrieve the model from the database. The existing model instance will not be affected:

If we have a look at the source code, the `fresh` method returns null if the model doesn't exists (for example if you create a `new Model`) or if it can't be found:

```php
/**
 * Reload a fresh model instance from the database.
 *
 * @param  array|string  $with
 * @return static|null
 */
public function fresh($with = [])
{
    if (! $this->exists) {
        return;
    }
    return static::newQueryWithoutScopes()
                ->with(is_string($with) ? func_get_args() : $with)
                ->where($this->getKeyName(), $this->getKey())
                ->first();
}
```

Now in your code you can just add a null check to achive your goal... something like:

```php
$user = Auth::user();
$user1 = Auth::user();
$user1->delete();

if($user->fresh()){
     // !== null => it exists
} else {
     // === null => it doesn't exists
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use can do that with method 'find()' like this :

```
   $user=Users:find(Auth::id())

   if($user)
     {
      //user is exist
     }
```